# Why is my program outputting an integer instead of a float?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that calculates the average ages of 3 people, with the input being the ages (integers), and the output being the average (float).

But every output always rounds to be an integer rather than a float. I'm using C.

```
int a, b, c;
float average;

printf("Enter your ages:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);

average = (a + b + c)/3;
printf("\n The average age of ABC is %f", average);
```

Also, any advice on how to more neatly get the age inputs would be nice, is this the best way to do it?

Comment: The expression `(a + b + c) / 3` gets evaluated as an `int` because all elements in it are `int`, including `3` which is implicitly `int`. You have to put at least one `float` there to force floating point calculation. You can do that by changing that `3` to a  `3.0f` (float) or `3.0` (double).

Comment: "and the output being the average (float)." --> Curious, why do  you want the output to be a `float` versus any floating-point type?

Answer (score 7):

> But every output always rounds to be an integer rather than a float

All you need is this:

```
 float average = (a + b + c)/3.0f;
```

Note you need `3.0f` to force the calculation to floating point. Otherwise it would only treat it as integer only (as all `a,b,c` are all integer).

You can remove the initial declaration of `average` and instead declare it and initialise it at the same time as above.

As pointed out by @Patrick the suffix `f` here is useful as without it the calculation would be default to `double` instead of `float`, and there would be a redundant downcast when the assignment is occurred.

> Also, any advice on how to more neatly get the age inputs would be nice, is this the best way to do it?

```
scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

Not sure if there's a best way. But that `scanf` look ok for the input.

Comment: Ohhh, okay, thanks a lot! Do you also have any tips on using scanf to gather more than one input? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: @ming your `scanf` looks fine

Comment: Probably be better to use `3.0f` so you don't waste cycles calculating a `double` just to downcast it to a `float`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, artm "don't waste cycles calculating a double just to downcast it to a float"  is a lost micro-optimization as `printf("\n The average age of ABC is %f", average);` just up converts `average` to a `double` for that call.  Using `double` throughout would make most sense here.  `double` also typically does not result in rounding a large `int` like `float` does. (Although doubtful an "age" is a large `int`.)

Comment: "Using double throughout would make most sense here" - ok thanks @chux

Answer (score 2):

This is the way calculation inflect data types.

When an `int` operates with an `int`, the result will be still an `int` too. If the result contains decimal part, it simply get discarded due to type casting to `int`.

But if an `int` operates with an `double` or `float`, the result will be with a corresponding type of `double` or `float`.

So what you need to do is just to make any of the operand into a decimal type. For example

```
average = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
```

or

```
average = (float) (a + b + c) / 3;
```

are both OK.

Answer (score 2):

*`>>>> ...the input being the ages (integers), and the output being the average (float)...`*

Look at the expression:

```
average = (a + b + c)/3;
   |      |_________| |
 float        int    integer constant
```

The right hand side of the expression is all `int`, so the output of this expression will `int` type and not `float`. This expression end up assigning the `int` value to a `float` type variable.

To fix this problem, you should be aware of the implicit type promotion and conversion rules. From [Default type promotions and conversions](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx4cb.html)

> If an operation involves two operands, and one of them is of type float, the other one is converted to float.

*[There are few rules above this rule and it applies only when those rules doesn't]*

So, in the expression `(a + b + c)/3`, if we change the `integer constant` to `float constant` then the whole expression resultant will be of type `float`.

```
average = (a + b + c)/3.0f;
```

*[An unsuffixed floating constant has type `double`. If suffix is the letter `f` or `F`, the floating constant has type `float`.]*

As per the type promotion rules, if you have any (or all) variable among `a`, `b` and `c` of type `float` the resultant value of the expression, with `integer constant`, will be of type `float`.

For example:

```
float a, b, c;

Or

int a, b;
float c;  // Of course you don't want to do this because in your example a, b and c
          // represents same thing and you want all of them to be of same type. 
          // This is just for the understanding.

average = (a + b + c)/3;
          |____________|
                 |
          The result of this will be of type float because at least one among a, b and c is 
          of type float and by the type promotion rule other will be promoted to float and 
          (a + b + c) will be calculated as all float type.
```

You can also use the type cast to solve the problem. But doing so also don't forget the type conversion rule.

For example, in the expression, you can do

```
either this
average = (float)(a + b + c)/3;

or this
average = (a + b + c)/(float)3;
```

With this, the resultant value of the expression will be of type `float` because the type of one of the operand of `/` operator is `float`. But if you do:

```
average = (float)((a + b + c)/3);
```

you will not get the desired result because the expression `(a + b + c)/3` will be calculated will all `int` and result produced will be of type `int` and it doesn't make any sense to type cast this after expression calculated.

*`>>>> Also, any advice on how to more neatly get the age inputs would be nice, is this the best way to do it?`*

In my opinion this is not the best way because this way the user cannot give exact age year/month/days (seems that you are taking only year as input). For practice these kind of example, this way may be okay as you are calculating average of `3` numbers but when you write some real world application where you have take age as input from user this way is not at all appropriate. Also, you are not doing any validation of the user input. The `10000000` or `-50` (negative value) is not valid input for age.